# Kivy ScrollView cutting off part of label

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am currently experiencing an issue when trying to use a GridLayout with a ScrollView, in that the top half of the labels in the GridLayout are being cut off by the ScrollView.
For example, here is what it currently looks like:
[image]

And, here is the .kv code for this section (it is part of a BottomNavigation):

```
MDBottomNavigationItem:
                id: hmNav
                name: 'home'
                text: 'Home'
                icon: 'home'
                GridLayout:
                    id: hmGrid
                    cols: 1
                    rows_minimum: {0: (self.parent.height) * 0.05, 1: (self.parent.height) * 0.2, 2: (self.parent.height) * 0.4, 3: (self.parent.height) * 0.1, 4: (self.parent.height) * 0.1}
                    row_force_default: True
                    MDLabel:
                        id: welcomeLabel
                        halign: 'center'
                        font_name: "DMSans"
                        text: "Hello, " + app.app.getId() + "!"
                        theme_text_color: "Custom"
                        font_size: '25sp'
                        size: self.texture_size
                        text_color: get_color_from_hex("#08421e")

                    MDLabel:
                        id: wLabel2
                        halign: 'center'
                        font_name: "DMSans"
                        text: "Here are your selected ingredients:"
                        theme_text_color: "Custom"
                        font_size: '15sp'
                        size: self.texture_size
                        text_color: get_color_from_hex("#08421e")

                    ScrollView:
                        id: selectedScroll
                        size: (self.parent.width, self.parent.height)
                        do_scroll_x: False
                        do_scroll_y: True
                        bar_width: 20

                        GridLayout:
                            id: selectedGrid
                            size_hint_y: None
                            spacing: 60
                            cols: 2
                            height: self.minimum_height
                            MDLabel:
                                halign: 'center'
                                text: "TEST1"
                                font_size: '15sp'
                                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                                text_color: get_color_from_hex("#08421e")
                                size: self.texture_size
                            MDLabel:
                                halign: 'center'
                                text: "TEST2"
                                font_size: '15sp'
                                size: self.texture_size
                            MDLabel:
                                halign: 'center'
                                text: "TEST1"
                                font_size: '15sp'
                                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                                text_color: get_color_from_hex("#08421e")
                                size: self.texture_size
                            MDLabel:
                                halign: 'center'
                                text: "TEST2"
                                font_size: '15sp'
                                size: self.texture_size
                            MDLabel:
                                halign: 'center'
                                text: "TEST1"
                                font_size: '15sp'
                                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                                text_color: get_color_from_hex("#08421e")
                                size: self.texture_size
                            MDLabel:
                                halign: 'center'
                                text: "TEST2"
                                font_size: '15sp'
                                size: self.texture_size

                    MDLabel:
                        halign: 'center'
                        text: "TEST 3"
                        font_size: '15sp'
                        size: self.texture_size

                    MDLabel:
                        halign: 'center'
                        text: "TEST 4"
                        font_size: '15sp'
                        size: self.texture_size
```

I have used a ScrollView with a BoxLayout successfully, using much of the same configuration as this GridLayout, but I'm unsure of why the top labels are being cut off in this particular instance.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `height: self.minimum_height` in a `GridLayout` (and others), it calculates the `height` of the `GridLayout` based on the `height` of its children. This means that those children must have explicit `height` values. You have specified `size: self.texture_size` for each `MDLabel`, but that will have no effect if `size_hint` is left at the default of `(1,1)`. To fix it, just add:

```
size_hint_y: None
```

to each of the `MDLabels`.